# Problems with RewriteRule in Xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am getting really crazy with the RewriteRule sentence in the .htaccess file using Xampp.

I am not using framework and what I have is:
The file system project root is D:\xampp_1.8.3\htdocs\my_project (here is the .htaccess file).
Inside I have a web/views folder (D:\xampp_1.8.3\htdocs\my_project\web\views) where the views (PHP files) are located.

My .htaccess file contains:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> Options FollowSymLinks
>
> RewriteBase /my_project/
>
> RewriteRule (Es|En)/([A-Za-z]+)$ web/views/page.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L]

and what I need is to receive the URL:

```
http://localhost/my_project/Es/Login
```

and transform it in:

```
http://localhost/my_project/web/views/page.php?page=Login&lang=Es
```

Nowadays Xampp shows me a blank page with no kind of error and I do not know why.
mod_rewrite module is on.

Comment: Open firebug and see what error you're getting in Net tab

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was not this one. Files path were not working on properly so the window was blank.